# How can I convert OSGB36 to latitude / longitude co-ordinates using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have to calculate distances between map points as part of a project I am doing. The map points are provided in OSGB36 co-ordinates, e.g. 508800 / 181100 (being easting and northing).  I have come across many functions to calculate the distance between 2 lat / longs and so would like to convert to these using VBA within an MS Access database.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Rectilinear coordinates like this actually need nothing more than 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem
to calculate distances.

```
$d = sqrt(pow($e1-$e2,2)+pow($n1-$n2,2));
```

Where $d is the answer in meters. $e1,$n1 and $e2,$n2 are your easting/northings of the two points.

Comment: I guess this doesnt actully answer the title question. But this is miles easier than converting to lat/long, the maths is insanely complicated (too much for a sql query) - and the distance formula in lat/long is more complicated than rectilinear anyway :).

Comment: Perfect, thanks Barry, so much easier than the other stuff I was looking at!